# Steam version of Dark Souls and GTA 4 crash on Windows 8

Tags: pc, dark-souls, grand-theft-auto-iv, windows-8

Is there a way to play Dark Souls on Windows 8 RTM? Think it crushes because of games for windows live client..
**UPD:** found the answer [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900179). 
see **Q. Dark Souls crashes and has a reference to XLive.dll, what do?**

Comment: Does Steam even support Windows 8 yet?

Comment: Sleeping Dogs, Portal 2 run well..Think thats not Steam issue.

Comment: If it's due to the GFWL client, then it's almost guaranteed a Steam problem; it's not meant to function on Windows 8.  Do you have any other Steam games that you know of that use GFWL?  Try that, and see if it crashes.  If it does, you have your problem.

Comment: GTA4. It cant start too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Steam installs an incompatible version of Games for Windows. Uninstall "Microsoft Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable", "Microsoft Games for Windows Marketplace" and then reinstall them from [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549)

Comment: By the way: here is the answer on my question: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900179

Comment: @0x49D1 Thank you for getting back to us. I hope I found the right bit of information from that post.

Comment: thanks. Its a bit strange that the question was closed..The problem really exists and may be someone will need the solution too.

Comment: @0x49D1 It's mostly the fact you gave us very little to work with :)

Comment: got 2 '-1' for it :D

Comment: @0x49D1 - Part of the problem is that Windows 8 has not even been released.  So problems you might have should be reported to Steam and the publisher.

Comment: @Ramhound That's wrong. Windows 8 has been out for a few days now through Dreamspark Premium and other programs. I'm using the final version right this second.

Answer (score 4):

I did the following and this worked for me:

- I uninstalled Microsoft Games for Windows and installed this [one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549) from the Microsoft website
- Right click on Grand Theft Auto IV in your Steam Library and select 'Properties'
- Select 'Local Files'
- Click 'Browse Local Files'
- Open the GTAIV folder
- Right click `LaunchGTAIV.exe` and select 'Run as Administrator'

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2900179) helped me greatly, but my own solution was a tiny bit different.

1. Remove GFWL and marketplace
2. Run the GFWL installer ([download link](http://sdrv.ms/O2WvBt) - downloads from MS/Xbox websites did *not* work)
3. Check Windows 7 compatibility mode for `DARKSOULS.exe`, but ***not*** for `DATA.exe`.
4. Uncheck all administrator modes and play the game normally through Steam.

Even one of these wrong and either GFWL would not load, or the game would crash before splash screen.